# Postgis spatial function not working with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgis

I have native query for a JpaRespository as:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Feature f WHERE f.feature_type = :featureType AND " +
            "ST_DWithin(geometry, 'SRID=:srid;POINT(:lon :lat 0)', :range)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Query generated is as:

```
SELECT * FROM Feature f WHERE f.feature_type = ? AND ST_DWithin(geometry,'SRID=:srid;POINT(:lon :lat 0)', ?)
```

geometry is a column in table containing spatial data.

But traces also tell that query have a parse error:

```
Hint: "SR" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

But when I execute query in database, I get results correctly.

Why this mismatch?

I could finally solve it by:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Feature f WHERE f.feature_type = :featureType AND " +
            "ST_DWithin(geometry, ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=' || :srid || ';POINT(' || :lon ||' ' || :lat || ' 0)'), :range)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding parameter inside a string literal that's why no bind parameter replaced.

```
'SRID=:srid;POINT(:lon :lat 0)'
```

You can create a string using this data and pass the whole string in the method.

Another way is using database concat operation but parameters needs to be string

```
'SRID=' || :srid|| ';POINT(' || :lon ||' ' || :lat || ' 0)'
```

Full query like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Feature f WHERE f.feature_type = :featureType AND " +
            "ST_DWithin(geometry, 'SRID=' || :srid || ';POINT(' || :lon ||' ' || :lat || ' 0)', :range)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Or use Database functions

```
ST_DWithin(geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point( :lon, :lat), :srid), :range)
```

Comment: This throws:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function st_dwithin(geometry, text, double precision) is not unique
  Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Passing string may help.

Comment: Check the function definition may be function is not unique based on data. That obviously your passing data problem

Comment: Strange. Fcuntion has 2 diff variants, with varyign number of parameters.https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Comment: Here what is first parameter of `st_dwithin` function ?

Comment: Its a geometry.

Comment: It has any value ? means it's is db column ? You need to pass value for 1st parameter or db column